# Why I can't bind label's tag to sql data?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, label

I am trying to use Label's Tag for editing it's Text property. I want to bind Label's Tag to a data member and change it to define Label's Text.

I Create a new Binding like this:

```
//
//Create Label For JoinDate Content
//
Label lblJDC = new UniLib_Label();
lblJDC.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;

lblJDC.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Tag", CurrentUserDataBindingSource, "PersonJoinDate"));
if (lblJDC.Tag != null)
{
     DateTime joinDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lblJDC.Tag);
     lblJDC.Text = new dateFunctions().shamsi(joinDate);
}
lblJDC.Location = new Point(280, 0);
lblJDC.AutoSize = true;
grp.Controls.Add(lblJDC);
```

But I get null value for Tag and when I try this code for Text it is ok and I get the correct value.

What is the problem?

Comment: Is this code running before form load, during the form load or later?

Comment: @IvanStoev 
This label belongs to a panel which will create dynamically after form load. and after that the panel will be add to the form.

Comment: Binding to `Tag` works just fine..: `label1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Tag", ds, "covers.text", true));
            if (label1.Tag != null) label1.Text = label1.Tag.ToString();`You probably have some other problem, maybe with your conversionsor your data..

Comment: There is no difference between data binding to `Tag` or `Text` property as @TaW said, but here, you expect data binding work before adding control to the form, while you should first add the control to form to make data binding work, then if you need to make it invisible, you can set it's visible property to false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data binding will work when you add the control in visible state to the form.
Once you setup data binding with this conditions, it will continue working even if the control goes invisible.

The below code will work as expected and shows the value of data field:

```
var label = new Label();
label.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Tag", yourBindingSource, "DataField"));
var panel = new Panel();
panel.Controls.Add(label);
this.Controls.Add(panel);
MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", label.Tag));
```

If you comment `panel.Controls.Add(label);` or comment `this.Controls.Add(panel);`or set the `visible` property of panel or label to false before adding the control to form, it will not work.

Comment: This is amazing but true. Looks like DataBinding only works if the control is a visible part of a (visible) controls.collection.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei
You're right. It worked correctly after I added it to the form.